# Indirect Only check for collections - Full Data path

Tags: path, collections

Why is there no option to copy full data path of the indirect only check in collections? It's possible for "selectable", "disable in renders" but not for "holdout" and "indirect only".

[image: indirect only check]

`bpy.data.collections["Collection name"].hide_select` - this is a full data path for "selectable"

When you hover your mouse over "indirect only" it shows this:

[image: data path from]

So the full data path would be:

```
bpy.data.collections["Collection name"].indirect_only
```

but it isn't as it doesn't work.

I need it for using in this addon: https://blendermarket.com/products/renderstacknode to set it as a property:

[image: Property]

[Set collection as Indirect Only (ie. = Shadowcatcher) through python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154256/set-collection-as-indirect-only-ie-shadowcatcher-through-python) - in this thread someone proposed using the code below:

```
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.indirect_only
```

And it works but it doesn't take into account the name of the collection, it just uses the active collection which doesn't satisfy me as it would add much manual work to the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way it's presented in the outliner is a bit confusing. What you have to understand is [Collections](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/collections/collections.html) have global properties :

- `hide_select` [image]
- `hide_viewport` [image]
- `hide_render` [image]

And view layer properties, which are accessed with a [LayerCollection](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.LayerCollection.html) object :

- `exclude` [image]
- `hide_viewport` [image] (I know, it's presented as the same path as the monitor icon one, but bear with me)
- `holdout` [image]
- `indirect_only` [image]

Global properties are accessed in a straightforward way, ie `bpy.data.collections["Collection"].hide_select = True` for instance. This will make the collection unselectable across ALL view layers. Same goes for viewport and render visibility.

View layer- related properties are accessed by their relative `layer_collection` which is a property of one and only one `view_layer`. Each collection has a related `layer_collection` object for each `view_layer` in the current scene. This object is responsible for holding and modifying its view layer properties.

The tricky part is collections don't hold a direct reference to their (theoretically infinite number of) `layer_collection` counterparts. You have to traverse the entire view layer's layer collections to test against the current collection, and only then can you change its properties. (I'd love to be corrected if there is an easier way).

Note that `LayerCollection` does have a direct reference to its unique `collection` object. (`layer_coll.collection`)

It then becomes really similar to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/137866/86891).

```
import bpy

def traverse_tree(t):
    yield t
    for child in t.children:
        yield from traverse_tree(child)

coll_name = "Collection"
layer_coll_master = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection

for layer_coll in traverse_tree(layer_coll_master):
    if layer_coll.collection.name == coll_name:
        layer_coll.indirect_only = False
        break
```

I guess the short answer to your question is, no, you can't change this property with a one-liner expression in python. (Again, please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: OK, I understand it, though it's still not very logical to me from a user's point of view.
I'm looking for a perfect workflow in my projects and every time I'm close there's a problem but now I'm the closest to the perfect solution. I think I'll create different view layers and access them with the addon, which is also possible and it's not that much more work in my case.

Comment: Another solution which I didn't mention is temporarily change the active collection and use `bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.indirect_only` as you found out at first, then reverting the active collection back after. But it may have unintended consequences...

Comment: Yeah, I though about it but I think I'll stick with a simpler solution for now :). Thank you anyway.